# Remove Tomcat 8080 port from the url on LAMP Server

Tags: apache, http, tomcat, lamp

I have a webapp hosted on tomcat.

Whenever I want to acess the app I have to use :8080 following my URL

(eg: webapp.mydomain.com:8080).

I can't change the port on which Tomcat is listening to 80 because I need Apache to listen it.

Is there any way that allow me to acess my app using simple url **webapp.mydomain.com** ?

Comment: Take a looke at http://kbeezie.com/apache-with-nginx/ not sure if thats what your looking for though.

Answer (score 0):

One easy option is to add a `VirtualServer` with a `ProxyPass` rule to your Apache configuration (either `httpd.conf`, or a different config file in `$APACHE_HOME/conf.d`).

This will tell `Apache` to listen to requests on a specific domain, and forward those requests that match the domain onto a different host / port.

Here's an example which will forward all requests to that domain (denoted by /) and send to a local `Tomcat` running on port `8080`. I've also added logging example so you can check it working:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName webapp.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias webapp

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/webapp_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/webapp_access.log combined
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/webapp.log simple

</VirtualHost>
```

Apache VirtualHost docs:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/

This needs the [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) `Apache` module. It might be installed already.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped me a lot and my question is resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

You should configure Tomcat with Apache using AJP Connector/mod_jk(the Tomcat redirector module).

There are many articles if you google :

- [Apache Tomcat Connector - Webserver HowTo](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html)
- [Tomcat and Apache Setup](http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/java_app/tomcat6/tomcat6_apache_server.htm)
- [Integrating Tomcat and Apache](http://www.slideshare.net/mohanraj_nagasamy/integrating-tomcat-and-apache-on-windows-presentation)

Comment: @Catarina Jorge - Have you gone through any of theses links for Integrating Tomcat and Apache?

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your reply.
I have already tested the two solutions, and both solved my question. I don't know which to use, guess I'll test each one a few days to realize which gets a better performance...
Once again, thank you!